# A shapefile / boundary coordinates for Bangladesh divisions

Tags: shapefile, data, coordinates, bangladesh

Are there any shapefiles on the boundary coordinates for each of the Bangladesh administration divisions?

Essentially what I want to achieve is to have the minimum and maximum of the longitudes & latitudes of three divisions: Khulna, Barisal & Chittagong so I can create a rough mask for these regions.

I have used this [link](http://www.gadm.org/download) to obtain the Bangladesh shapefile but does not give me the individual division borders, or that I can see when using ArcGis Explorer.

I was thinking, if I had the data for the border coordinates I could extract the min & max values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to your data link the bounding boxes are-

Khulna: 24.209739, 89.964997, 21.650730, 88.559281

Barisal: 23.071161, 91.001115, 21.737791, 89.864068

Chittagong: 24.269250, 92.673661, 20.741111, 90.539200

Comment: Thank you, how did you get these boundaries?

Comment: I used ArcGIS to get the values. Can u please mark it as answered question?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at UN FAO's [GAUL database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Administrative_Unit_Layers)